# Metal Deform In BGE

Tags: game-engine

How would I simulate deforming metal in the game engine? I want something similar to a car crash or a can being crushed. I have tried softbody physics but it does not look like metal but more like clay.

Comment: Does it need to be physically accurate in real time or is a premade animation ok?

Comment: Preferably realtime.